# My keyboard layout is all wrong.. And hotkeys aren't working!

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 14.10

I'm very new at Ubuntu (I'm a recent Windows convert)

Basically when I first set up the OS I chose the keyboard layout as "English (UK)" and it's got the @ and " keys messed up! I have no idea where to find and change these settings.. I have looked around the forums a few times already and found answers that  didn't really fit my situation.. I'm just looking for where I can change that!

Also using shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> that are used in certain tutorials just don't work for me!

I'm sorry if these questions have been asked before and I have used Terminal a little but I'm no pro so if you can, please dumb down the instructions a little for me :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay so after spending literally hours trying to find an answer I managed to find an application to fix it and allow me to switch and all is good now...